# Set Selecpicker val and set option as selected dynamically

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

**Question metadata**

**Bootstrap selectpicker version** :  Selectpicker.VERSION = '1.7.2';

**jQuery version** : jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.2

**Problem statement** :

I have a filter `select` list. On selecting an `option` (a filter), server responds with entire filter details. Based on returned data, I need to set couple of `select` elements (bootstrap selects). Once the value is set I also need to set that `option` as selected.

Selects Elements Markup (all have distinct id's)

```
<select id="pspName" class="form-control selectpicker"> <!--Options --> </select>
<select id="pmName" class="form-control selectpicker"> <!--Options --> </select>
<select id="countryName" class="form-control selectpicker"> <!--Options --> </select>
.
.
.
<select id="currencyName" class="form-control selectpicker"> <!--Options --> </select>
```

jQuery code :

Selecpicker initialization works well :

```
 //all at once.
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

Code tried but with no luck. So require assistance for the same is as follows,

I tried with usual conventions of find `option` by `value` but it did not work well, e.g. for `select` with `id` as `pspName` get `option` by `value` and trigger `click`. But it failed to refresh the `select` and it is also not set to `selected`.

```
 $('select#pspName option[value="server_returned_value"]').click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a specific method to set the values:

```
$('#countryName').selectpicker('val', 'Japan');
```

I've created a small example to setup several elements based on a set of attributes :

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r_costa/zL23pf3n/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you make the city changed based on country selected?

Comment: Do you have a list of cities for each country ? I don't know how your data is structured

Comment: In your example I was referring to. that will suffice to me.

Comment: You were referring to what ?

Comment: Set city programtically on selecting country. Also it should be set as selected.

Comment: Check my fiddle again and see if it suits your needs. I'm not sure what you mean by 'it should be set as selected' - do you want a default value ?

Comment: what i want is, when in your fiddle if i select France then Paris should selected, for Russia automatically Moscow should be set as selected and shown.

Comment: Done. Test the fiddle and see if it's working as intended.